# Office 365 Unified API authentication request doesn't redirect to login (vs. Azure AD that does)

Tags: azure, office365

I just replaced my app OAUTH2 authentication from Azure AD to Office 365 Unified API (i.e., switched from login.**windows.net** to login.**microsoftonline.com**). Problem is that login.microsoftonline.com returns 200 to the authentication request, instead of 302 (redirect) that the login.windows.net does (which is what should be returned by the unified API as well - see respective documentation on MSDN.

Here is an example - [Office 365 Unfied API](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=c3d529a5-a017-4cd3-8c62-04dafd43d64d&redirect_uri=https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/&resource=https:%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F&state=2cf22008-07e3-48d6-a6a6-02dae900e774&prompt=login) vs. [Azure AD](https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=c3d529a5-a017-4cd3-8c62-04dafd43d64d&redirect_uri=https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/&resource=https:%2F%2Foutlook.office365.com%2F&state=2cf22008-07e3-48d6-a6a6-02dae900e774&prompt=login). Both get you to the Microsoft login page but only Azure AD redirects you there (i.e., returns 302).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

login.microsoftonline.com is not exclusively used for Office 365 unified API. This is an update the AAD team did for all flows a few months back:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/03/06/simplifying-our-azure-ad-authentication-flows.aspx

Comment: Got it - no more initial redirect. I'd suggest stating this explicitly in https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/get-started-with-office-365-unified-api#msg_get_app_authorized (or adding the link you've shared).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, we will make the update to the doc